# How to copy multiple files with Tcl file command

Tags: tcl

From Tcl online manual I see that Tcl's file copy command can take multiple source files as argument:

```
file copy ?-force? ?--? source ?source ...? targetDir
```

However, I have the following code:

```
set flist [list a.txt b.txt]
file copy $flist [file join D:\\ test dest]
```

And get this error message:
    error copying "a.txt b.txt": no such file or directory

How do I properly pass a file list as source argument to the file copy command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use expansion:

```
file copy {*}$flist {D:\test\dest}
```

The `{*}` substitutes the words of the list given by what follows it as separate words; it's precisely right here.

I've also written the destination directory as a brace-quoted literal.

---

Still on Tcl 8.4 or before? Upgrade! Or use this:

```
eval file copy $flist [list {D:\test\dest}]
```

It's quite a lot harder to use `eval` right than `{*}`, so *really* upgrade.

Or even do:

```
foreach f $flist {
    file copy $f {D:\test\dest}
}
```

Given that IO operations will dominate the performance, you shouldn't notice any speed difference for doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem! I'm using Tcl 8.6 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the list is passed as a whole to the command instead of individual elements. Use {*} operator to break the list down to its individual elements.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is don't use a list the way you have done. 
This works in your example:

```
set flist "a.txt b.txt"
file copy $flist [file join D:\\ test dest]
```

More correct would be to use the list expansion {*} syntax.

Comment: Actually, `"a.txt b.txt"` is exactly equivalent to `[list a.txt b.txt]`, so this suggestion does not change or solve anything.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow No, it's not exactly equivalent. if you actually ran my code, you would have seen it worked. But, thanks for the downvote anyway - it means a lot to me.

Comment: You know, I *did* run your code just to make sure I wasn't missing anything. And no, it didn't work. Please explain how the expressions would be different: by the syntactic rules of Tcl, they are the same.